# re.sub how to do it in one step?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I try to put this steps in one, but it doesnt work

```
w = re.sub('[0-9]', r'9', w)
w = re.sub('[A-Z]', r'X', w)
w = re.sub('[a-z]', r'x', w)
```

Does anybody knows how to make from such strings as `XXxxxx999` --> `Xx9`.

Comment: Настя, you may use a callback method as the replacement argument. There, you may apply custom replacement logic, just build your regex with capturing groups. like `([0-9])|([A-Z])|[a-z]`, and then analyze which group matched.

Comment: I understood it would be like that, but i dont understand how to make in replacement some options  w = re.sub('([0-9])|([A-Z])|([a-z])', r'9', w)

Comment: `re.sub(r'([0-9])|([A-Z])|[a-z]', repl, w)` where `repl` is `def repl(m):....`, just check `if m.group(1)` then it is a digit, `if m.group(2)` then it is an uppercase letter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a callback method as a replacement argument like this:

```
import re

rx = r'([0-9]+)|([A-Z]+)|[a-z]+'
w = "XXxxxx999"

def repl(m):
    if m.group(1):       # if ([0-9]) matched
        return '9'       # replace with 9
    elif m.group(2):     # if ([A-Z]) matched
        return 'X'       # replace with X
    else:                # if ([a-z]) matched
        return 'x'       # replace with x

print(re.sub(rx, repl, w)) # => Xx9
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/iPPeVF).

The regex matches:

- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1: 1+ digits
- `|` - or
- `([A-Z]+)` - Group 2: 1+  uppercase letters
- `|` - or
- `[a-z]+` - 1+ lowercase letters.

Comment: great, thanks I am new in programming so I have learned today somthing. Can you laso help me with the second question ?I found some solutions for this problem, but only if we want to eliminate all the characters, that appear in the string, and not like in my case.

    input = "XXXxxx999XX"
    output = "Xx9X"

Comment: @NastjaKryvoscheya Do you mean https://ideone.com/iPPeVF ? Use `rx = r'([0-9]+)|([A-Z]+)|[a-z]+'` where `+` quantifier is added to match 1 or more occurrences of each subpattern.