# Python regex modify a group match in re.sub()

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have written a regex to identify the words only starting, only ending with a single quote `(')` or both starting/ending:

```
re_quotes_front = r"(?:\s+|^)(?P<g1>'\w+)(?=\s+|$)"
re_quotes_end = r"(?:\s+|^)(?P<g2>\w+')(?=\s+|$)"
re_quotes_front_end = r"(?:\s+|^)(?P<g3>'\w+')(?=\s+|$)"
generic_quotes = r"%s|%s|%s" % (re_quotes_front, re_quotes_end, re_quotes_front_end)
```

Now I want to replace the matching group with a space between `'` and the matched `word`.

For example, let's say we have to match the regex with the below string:

`snippet = "shot perhaps 'artistically' with 'handheld cameras 'devices'"`

I want to replace all of them using one regex, i.e., `generic_quotes`. Can that be done?

The output should be:

```
"shot perhaps ' artistically ' with ' handheld cameras ' devices '"
```

Even for any one of the regex, the below does not work:

`result = re.sub(re_quotes_front, r"\g<g1>".replace("'", " ' "), snippet)`

I should get the word `'handheld` converted to `' handheld` (note the space before and after the quote) and that's not happening. I couldn't understand how this is working. Rather, I am getting the output:

`"shot perhaps 'artistically' with'handheld cameras'em 'asdsd'"`

How can I reference the word using the `<group_name1>` and modify it?

Comment: artistically and devices also start with a single quote. Why aren't they affected?

Comment: I suspect you need `re.sub(r"(\s|^)(')(\w+)(?=\s|$)", r'\1\2 \3', text)`, see https://regex101.com/r/XZFqYG/2. Surely you may [use a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53282036) where you could modify the whole match value, but it will be less efficient

Comment: Can you modify the regex? Or only code? The point is, it is much harder to modify  just a group contents inside `re.sub`, it is easier to capture substrings and use backreferences in the string replacement pattern.

Comment: @CinCout : The regex is to match only the words beginning with quote and not the word both beginning and ending with quote. Hence, only `'handheld`

Comment: So, please explain, update the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Updated. I don't know was I able to frame it properly or not. Please let me know if the updated question is confusing. I wanted to understand why the `.replace("'"," ' ")` doesn't work in `re.sub()`. Thanks!

Comment: It is already answered on SO: the `r"\g<g1>".replace("'", " ' ")` just returns `\g<g1>` and this is the replacement pattern. You do not replace quotes in the match, you replace them in the `\g<g1>` string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks Wiktor. I got the point, I got a workaround as below, which is not efficient I know:
`result = re.sub(generic_quotes, add_spaces, temp)

def add_spaces(match_obj):
    match_str = match_obj.group(0)
    result = match_str.replace("'", " ' ")
    return " " + result.strip()`

Comment: Just use a lambda or a `def` as the replacement argument.

Comment: I have a question, if I do a match_obj.group(1), I get an error. I have modified the regex as:
`re_quotes_front = r"(?:\s+|^)(')(\w+)(?=\s+|$)"
re_quotes_end = r"(?:\s+|^)(\w+)(')(?=\s+|$)"
re_quotes_front_end = r"(?:\s+|^)(')(\w+)(')(?=\s+|$)"
generic_quotes = r"%s|%s|%s" % (re_quotes_front, re_quotes_end, re_quotes_front_end)`

There is group 1 in all the regex then why the error?